# Create a Gabor filter by applying Gabor equation using matlab

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, matlab

I tried to create a Gabor Filter. We all know that this kind of filter is more complex than any other filters because it is characterized by more complex features such as having different scales and orientations.
The equation of Gabor filter is:

[image]

To create such a Gabor filter with a specific scale and direction, the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gabor_filter) gives to us a simple matlab code about that:

```
sigma_x = sigma;
sigma_y = sigma/gamma;

nstds = 3;
xmax = max(abs(nstds*sigma_x*cos(theta)),abs(nstds*sigma_y*sin(theta)));
xmax = ceil(max(1,xmax));
ymax = max(abs(nstds*sigma_x*sin(theta)),abs(nstds*sigma_y*cos(theta)));
ymax = ceil(max(1,ymax));
xmin = -xmax; ymin = -ymax;
[x,y] = meshgrid(xmin:xmax,ymin:ymax);


x_theta=x*cos(theta)+y*sin(theta);
y_theta=-x*sin(theta)+y*cos(theta);

gb= exp(-.5*(x_theta.^2/sigma_x^2+y_theta.^2/sigma_y^2)).*cos(2*pi/lambda*x_theta+psi);
```

I want to know if this code is correct. I notice that the code above didn't respond exactly to the equation of Gabor filter. For example: in the code, we have :`sigma_x=sigma` and `sigma_y=sigma/gamma` ... and we have `gb=exp(-.5*(x_theta.....))`. I didn't understand what is the `5` in the equation..

Is the matlab code written above respond correctly to the equation of the Gabor filter?? please i need your opinion and if possible to optimize the code if it is not correct.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Replace below line in your code:

```
gb= exp(-.5*(x_theta.^2/sigma_x^2+y_theta.^2/sigma_y^2)).*cos(2*pi/lambda*x_theta+psi);
```

I replace the cos with sin in above matlab code.

Comment: Désolé, i edited my question, it is cos not sin :) by the way thank you for your answer :) ,,, but why exp(-.5 ... ,, why 5 ??

Comment: and why sigma_x = sigma; and sigma_y = sigma/gamma; ,,, is the code respond correcty to the equation ?

Comment: 1/2 = 0.5, and a/c +b/c can be written as (a+b)/2 and vice versa. So (x^2+gamma^2*y^2)/2*sigma^2 can be written as 0.5 *( (x^2/sigma^2) + (y^2*gama^2/sigma^2))

Comment: Are you getting problems still?

Comment: Yes i understood, Thank you so much :),, but why they represent the effective width sigma_y as sigma/gamma ? do you know why ?

Comment: In code: y_theta.^2/sigma_y^2, if you replace sigma/gamma then it will be same (y_theta.^2*gamma^2)/sigma^2. You can try it on paper.

Comment: Désolé for my question :( ,, i really thank you and i appreciated your answers very much! ,, i will accept your answer, but unfortunately i have only 10 reputations so i can't vote up to you. By the way, you can vote up to me, and i will have more than 15 reputations, then i will be able to vote up to you :) thank you again!!

Answer (score 3):

You can now create a Gabor filter bank using the [gabor](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/gabor.html) function in the image processing toolbox, and you can apply it to an image using [imgaborfilt](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imgaborfilt.html).

Comment: Aha great! they make it so easy now

Answer (score 1):

The formula is exp(-(...) / (2*sigma^2) ). Isn't it? 
So 1/2 = 0.5 = .5

Comment: Thank you for the answer :-)