# How to create 64 Gabor features at each scale and orientation in the spatial and frequency domain

Tags: matlab, image-processing, filter, filtering, convolution

**Normally, a Gabor filter, as its name suggests, is used to filter an image and extract everything that it is oriented in the same direction of the filtering.**

In this question, you can see more efficient code than written in this [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20147891/create-a-gabor-filter-by-applying-gabor-equation-using-matlab)

Assume 16 scales of Filters at 4 orientations, so we get 64 gabor filters.

**scales=[7:2:37], 7x7 to 37x37 in steps of two pixels, so we have 7x7, 9x9, 11x11, 13x13, 15x15, 17x17, 19x19, 21x21, 23x23, 25x25, 27x27, 29x29, 31x31, 33x33, 35x35 and 37x37.**

**directions=[0, pi/4, pi/2, 3pi/4].**

The equation of Gabor filter in the spatial domain is:

[image]

The equation of Gabor filter in the frequency domain is:
[image]

Comment: Ok, and what is your question?

Comment: I don't have question :). This is an efficient code to create Gabor filters.

Comment: You shouldn't post an answer as a question. Instead, post a question asking "how to create 64 Gabor filters" and answer this question yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In the spatial domain:**

```
function [fSiz,filters,c1OL,numSimpleFilters] = init_gabor(rot, RF_siz)    

    image=imread('xxx.jpg');
    image_gray=rgb2gray(image);
    image_gray=imresize(image_gray, [100 100]);
    image_double=double(image_gray);

    rot = [0 45 90 135]; % we have four orientations
                RF_siz    = [7:2:37]; %we get 16 scales (7x7 to 37x37 in steps of two pixels)
                minFS     = 7; % the minimum receptive field
                maxFS     = 37; % the maximum receptive field
                sigma  = 0.0036*RF_siz.^2 + 0.35*RF_siz + 0.18; %define the equation of effective width
                lambda = sigma/0.8; % it the equation of wavelength (lambda)
                G      = 0.3;   % spatial aspect ratio: 0.23 < gamma < 0.92


                numFilterSizes   = length(RF_siz); % we get 16

                numSimpleFilters = length(rot); % we get 4

                numFilters       = numFilterSizes*numSimpleFilters; % we get 16x4 = 64 filters

                fSiz             = zeros(numFilters,1); % It is a vector of size numFilters where each cell contains the size of the filter (7,7,7,7,9,9,9,9,11,11,11,11,......,37,37,37,37)

                filters          = zeros(max(RF_siz)^2,numFilters); % Matrix of Gabor filters of size %max_fSiz x num_filters, where max_fSiz is the length of the largest filter and num_filters the total number of filters. Column j of filters matrix contains a n_jxn_j filter (reshaped as a column vector and padded with zeros).




            for k = 1:numFilterSizes  
                for r = 1:numSimpleFilters
                    theta     = rot(r)*pi/180; % so we get 0, pi/4, pi/2, 3pi/4
                    filtSize  = RF_siz(k); 
                    center    = ceil(filtSize/2);
                    filtSizeL = center-1;
                    filtSizeR = filtSize-filtSizeL-1;
                    sigmaq    = sigma(k)^2;

                    for i = -filtSizeL:filtSizeR
                        for j = -filtSizeL:filtSizeR

                            if ( sqrt(i^2+j^2)>filtSize/2 )
                                E = 0;
                            else
                                x = i*cos(theta) - j*sin(theta);
                                y = i*sin(theta) + j*cos(theta);
                                E = exp(-(x^2+G^2*y^2)/(2*sigmaq))*cos(2*pi*x/lambda(k));
                            end
                            f(j+center,i+center) = E;
                        end
                    end

                    f = f - mean(mean(f));
                    f = f ./ sqrt(sum(sum(f.^2)));
                    p = numSimpleFilters*(k-1) + r;
                    filters(1:filtSize^2,p)=reshape(f,filtSize^2,1);
                    fSiz(p)=filtSize;
                end
            end

            % Rebuild all filters (of all sizes)

            nFilts = length(fSiz);
            for i = 1:nFilts
              sqfilter{i} = reshape(filters(1:(fSiz(i)^2),i),fSiz(i),fSiz(i));

            %if you will use conv2 to convolve an image with this gabor, so you should also add the equation below. But if you will use imfilter instead of conv2, so do not add the equation below.

                    sqfilter{i} = sqfilter{i}(end:-1:1,end:-1:1); %flip in order to use conv2 instead of imfilter (%bug_fix 6/28/2007);

    convv=imfilter(image_double, sqfilter{i}, 'same', 'conv');
    figure;

        imagesc(convv);
        colormap(gray);

                      end
```

Comment: Thanks for the code but I am eager to know the source for this code. I mean some document mentioning these details as I am confused about filter scale? Some say scale is the size of the filter like you mentioned RF_siz whereas others say that the scale is just the sigma value. Can you please explain what actually is scale. It will be better if you can provide some link to the document. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
phi = ij*pi/4; % ij = 0, 1, 2, 3
theta = 3;
sigma = 0.65*theta;
filterSize = 7;   % 7:2:37

G = zeros(filterSize);


for i=(0:filterSize-1)/filterSize
    for j=(0:filterSize-1)/filterSize
        xprime= j*cos(phi);
        yprime= i*sin(phi);
        K = exp(2*pi*theta*sqrt(-1)*(xprime+ yprime));
        G(round((i+1)*filterSize),round((j+1)*filterSize)) =...
           exp(-(i^2+j^2)/(sigma^2))*K;
    end
end
```

Comment: Dear Lennon, do you know how to apply the inverse Gabor filter in order to reconstruct the original image ? Thanks in advance!:)

Answer (score 1):

As of R2015b release of the Image Processing Toolbox, you can create a Gabor filter bank using the [gabor](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/gabor.html) function in the image processing toolbox, and you can apply it to an image using [imgaborfilt](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imgaborfilt.html).

Answer (score 0):

**In the frequency domain:**

```
sigma_u=1/2*pi*sigmaq;
sigma_v=1/2*pi*sigmaq;
u0=2*pi*cos(theta)*lambda(k);
v0=2*pi*sin(theta)*lambda(k);

for u = -filtSizeL:filtSizeR
            for v = -filtSizeL:filtSizeR

                if ( sqrt(u^2+v^2)>filtSize/2 )
                    E = 0;
                else
                    v_theta = u*cos(theta) - v*sin(theta);
                    u_theta = u*sin(theta) + v*cos(theta);

                  E=(1/2*pi*sigma_u*sigma_v)*((exp((-1/2)*(((u_theta-u0)^2/sigma_u^2))+((v_theta-v0)^2/sigma_v^2))) + (exp((-1/2)*(((u_theta+u0)^2/sigma_u^2))+((v_theta+v0)^2/sigma_v^2))));

                end
                f(v+center,u+center) = E;
            end
        end
```

Comment: which formula did you use to generate this code? why are you building the filter in frequency domain?

Comment: I used the formula in my edited question above. I extract the formula from the article that you gave to me in order to reduce the complexity. But in my tests, I noticed that the complexity remains the same in spatial and frequency domains. That's why i am not sure if I applied correctly the frequency formula in my code

Comment: your code looks good to me. But it seems like in frequency domain it is not separable