# Working on Separable Gabor filters in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, filtering, convolution

A filter g is called separable if it can be expressed as the multiplication of two vectors `grow` and `gcol` . Employing one dimensional filters decreases the two dimensional filter's computational complexity from `O(M^2 N^2)` to  `O(2M N^2)` where M and N are the width (and height) of the filter mask and the image respectively.

In [this stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20921698/how-to-create-64-gabor-features-at-each-scale-and-orientation-in-matlab), I wrote the equation of a Gabor filter in the spatial domain, then I wrote a matlab code which serves to create 64 gabor features.

According to the definition of separable filters, the Gabor filters are parallel to the image axes - `theta = k*pi/2 where k=0,1,2,etc.`. So if theta=pi/2 ==> the equation in [this stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20921698/how-to-create-64-gabor-features-at-each-scale-and-orientation-in-matlab) can be rewritten as:

[image]

The equation above is extracted from [this article](http://www.cse.unr.edu/~amayeh/index_files/papers/isvc09.pdf).

**Note:** theta can be extented to be equal `k*pi/4.` By comparing to the equation in [this stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/20921804/edit), we can consider that `f= 1 / lambda`.

**By changing my previous code in [this stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20921698/how-to-create-64-gabor-features-at-each-scale-and-orientation-in-matlab/20921804#20921804), I wrote a matlab code to make the Gabor filters separable by using the equation above, but I am sure that my code below is not correct especially when I initialized the `gbp` and `glp` equations. That is why I need your help. I will appreciate your help very much.**

*Let's show now my code:*

```
    function [fSiz,filters1,filters2,c1OL,numSimpleFilters] = init_gabor(rot, RF_siz)

    image=imread('xxx.jpg');
    image_gray=rgb2gray(image);
    image_gray=imresize(image_gray, [100 100]);
    image_double=double(image_gray);

     rot = [0 45 90 135]; % we have four orientations
                    RF_siz    = [7:2:37]; %we get 16 scales (7x7 to 37x37 in steps of two pixels)
                    minFS     = 7; % the minimum receptive field
                    maxFS     = 37; % the maximum receptive field
                    sigma  = 0.0036*RF_siz.^2 + 0.35*RF_siz + 0.18; %define the equation of effective width
                    lambda = sigma/0.8; % it the equation of wavelength (lambda)
                    G      = 0.3;   % spatial aspect ratio: 0.23 < gamma < 0.92


                    numFilterSizes   = length(RF_siz); % we get 16

                    numSimpleFilters = length(rot); % we get 4

                    numFilters       = numFilterSizes*numSimpleFilters; % we get 16x4 = 64 filters

                    fSiz             = zeros(numFilters,1); % It is a vector of size numFilters where each cell contains the size of the filter (7,7,7,7,9,9,9,9,11,11,11,11,......,37,37,37,37)
filters1          = zeros(max(RF_siz),numFilters);
filters2          = zeros(numFilters,max(RF_siz));

for k = 1:numFilterSizes  
    for r = 1:numSimpleFilters
        theta     = rot(r)*pi/180;
        filtSize  = RF_siz(k);
        center    = ceil(filtSize/2);
        filtSizeL = center-1;
        filtSizeR = filtSize-filtSizeL-1;
        sigmaq    = sigma(k)^2;

        for x = -filtSizeL:filtSizeR

                    fx = exp(-(x^2)/(2*sigmaq))*cos(2*pi*x/lambda(k));
                       f1(x+center,1) = fx;
        end
                      for y = -filtSizeL:filtSizeR
                    gy = exp(-(y^2)/(2*sigmaq));
                    f2(1,y+center) = gy;
                      end



        f1 = f1 - mean(mean(f1));
        f1 = f1 ./ sqrt(sum(sum(f1.^2)));
         f2 = f2 - mean(mean(f2));
        f2 = f2 ./ sqrt(sum(sum(f2.^2)));
        p = numSimpleFilters*(k-1) + r;
        filters1(1:filtSize,p)=f1;
        filters2(p,1:filtSize)=f2;

        convv1=imfilter(image_double,  filters1(1:filtSize,p),'conv');
        convv2=imfilter(double(convv1),  filters2(p,1:filtSize),'conv');
        figure
        imagesc(convv2);
        colormap(gray);

    end
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the code is correct provided your previous version of Gabor filter code is correct too. The only thing is that if `theta = k * pi/4;`, your formula [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20921698/how-to-create-64-gabor-features-at-each-scale-and-orientation-in-matlab) should be separated to:

```
fx = exp(-(x^2)/(2*sigmaq))*cos(2*pi*x/lambda(k));
gy = exp(-(G^2 * y^2)/(2*sigmaq));
```

To be consistent, you may use

```
f1(1,x+center) = fx;
f2(y+center,1) = gy;
```

or keep `f1` and `f2` as it is but transpose your `filters1` and `filters2` thereafter.
Everything else looks good to me.

**EDIT**

My answer above works for `theta = k * pi/4;`, with other angles, based on your paper,

```
x = i*cos(theta) - j*sin(theta);
y = i*sin(theta) + j*cos(theta);
fx = exp(-(x^2)/(2*sigmaq))*exp(sqrt(-1)*x*cos(theta));
gy = exp(-(G^2 * y^2)/(2*sigmaq))*exp(sqrt(-1)*y*sin(theta));
```

Comment: Firstly, thank you very much for your reply. But we all know that theta=k*pi/4. So in this case, fx and gy remains the same? can you please show this link: "http://cbcl.mit.edu/publications/ai-publications/2011/MIT-CSAIL-TR-2011-021.pdf" . So I can use the fx and gy above even for theta=k*pi/4? or I should use the fx and gy written in the complex domain as written in the link? What is your opinion :)

Comment: @Christina thank you for the paper. It seems like you can separate the filter to fx and gy with any theta value (in formula 7 and 8), of course also inludes k*pi/4. It is not complex domain actually, because the final filter is just extracting the real value (formula 6)

Comment: In this case, by using the fx and gy in the link that I gave you, we don't need to use the interpolation to work in any orientation? because I red your article and they told that the separable don't work with any orientation (what does meant by "don't work with any orientation? it was meant that originally theta is equal to k*pi/2  and we should use the interpolation to work with theta=k*pi/4 and different than k*pi/4 ?? ")

Comment: And in the paper that you gave to me, they told that theta can be extended to be equal k*pi/4. So we need to change fx and gy or they remain the same? Really I thank you so much for your help!!

Comment: @Christina the paper i gave you did not include the theta information, but they rather assume it only extracts the horrizontal and vertical orientations. What shown in my answer is the fixed version, but you can include theta (any value should work) in the filter, then you can extract any orientations with the gabor:)

Comment: Sorry for my questions:D, So Can I use fx and gy given in your answer to work even with theta=k*pi/4 ? and to also work with any orientation (theta different than k*pi/4), so we should implement such an interpolation method? does my opinion is true ?

Comment: @Christina no need for interpolation, see my update in answer:)

Comment: No interpolation is used based on my paper, so why the interpolation was necessary based on your paper?

Comment: @Christina I think they are equivalent, but interpolation is computational-cost, now that you have the separable equation from a new paper, you don't need interpolation any more:)

Comment: If you notice that in the paper that you gave to me, they told that if theta=pi/2 ==> x_theta = x and y_theta=y. but if you compute with theta=pi/2, we should get: x_theta=xcos(pi/2)+ysin(pi/2)=0+y=y. so we get x_theta = y because cos(pi/2)=0 and sin(pi/2)=1 !!. So I am wrong or the authors in the paper are wrong ?

Comment: @Christina it occurs perhaps the definition of x_theta is different between 2 papers. They may use x_theta=xsin(theta)+ycos(theta); but it's not a big deal since you can still separate the filter with two orthogonal filters (90 degree difference).

Comment: But in the paper, they used x_theta=xcos(theta)+ysin(theta), so how they computed x_theta to be equal x when theta=pi/2!! If theta=0, so x_theta=x and y_theta=y !

Comment: @Christina the reviewers did not notice that probably, and since it is a special case with degree of 90, reverse x and y won't affect the result very much, so they pass :)

Comment: Or I think that according to the method of creating the Gabor filters, they used another formulas of x_theta and y_theta, I don't know. Anw thank you so much for your help:)

Comment: you are very welcome! the paper you provided later seems better for separable filter:)

Comment: Please can you add to your answer above, how in the paper that I gave to you they were computed the separability using the normalized cross-correlation? what is the value of zero mean,unit normal version of the filter?

Comment: @Christina sorry but I didn't see cross-correlation in their paper. Can you re-start a new question, and let me know the formulas you mentioned there? I will try to answer the question then. Thanks

Comment: I wrote the final code below, but please I don't think that it is true. Please can you help me? I also got an error with imagesc because it is not working with complex domain. And when I use imshow, the convolution results are very bad!

Comment: when I wrote if x=:-filtsizeL:filtsizeR, then calculate fx , and the same thing for gy, I am sure that it is completely false. Please I need your appreciated help :(

Comment: Please can you correct my code below, test it in your pc and show me your results please. I am so sorry, but really I will appreciate very much your help!

Comment: @Christina Sure, I will take a look later today:)

Comment: Thank you! I think that the computation should be: I(x,y)*real[fx X gy]=real[I(x,y)*(fx X gy)]=real[I(x,y)*fx*gy].I will wait you until you be available :) good luck:)

Comment: Hello!, I was trying to achieve something similar in C#/C++ some time ago, (you can see my previous post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12878754/how-to-convolve-an-image-with-different-gabor-filters-adjusted-according-to-the), But I have not been able to figure out how to separate the Filter, this seems to be the solution to my problem but I fail to understand MatLab syntax, also it seems that the link to the paper that @lennon310 posted is broken :(.

Answer (score 0):

**The final code will be:**

```
function [fSiz,filters1,filters2,c1OL,numSimpleFilters] = init_gabor(rot, RF_siz)

            image=imread('xxx.jpg');
            image_gray=rgb2gray(image);
            image_gray=imresize(image_gray, [100 100]);
            image_double=double(image_gray);

             rot = [0 45 90 135];
                            RF_siz    = [7:2:37]; 
                            minFS     = 7; 
                            maxFS     = 37; 
                            sigma  = 0.0036*RF_siz.^2 + 0.35*RF_siz + 0.18; 
                            lambda = sigma/0.8; 
                            G      = 0.3;   


                            numFilterSizes   = length(RF_siz); 

                            numSimpleFilters = length(rot); 

                            numFilters       = numFilterSizes*numSimpleFilters; 

                            fSiz             = zeros(numFilters,1); 
                            filters1          = zeros(max(RF_siz),numFilters);
                            filters2          = zeros(numFilters,max(RF_siz));

        for k = 1:numFilterSizes  
            for r = 1:numSimpleFilters
                theta     = rot(r)*pi/180;
                filtSize  = RF_siz(k);
                center    = ceil(filtSize/2);
                filtSizeL = center-1;
                filtSizeR = filtSize-filtSizeL-1;
                sigmaq    = sigma(k)^2;

                for x = -filtSizeL:filtSizeR

                            fx = exp(-(x^2)/(2*sigmaq))*exp(sqrt(-1)*x*cos(theta));
                               f1(1, x+center) = fx;
                end
                              for y = -filtSizeL:filtSizeR
                            gy=exp(-(y^2)/(2*sigmaq))*exp(sqrt(-1)*y*sin(theta));
                            f2(y+center,1) = gy;
                              end


         f1 = f1 - mean(mean(f1));
            f1 = f1 ./ sqrt(sum(sum(f1.^2)));
             f2 = f2 - mean(mean(f2));
            f2 = f2 ./ sqrt(sum(sum(f2.^2)));
            p = numSimpleFilters*(k-1) + r;

            filters1(1:filtSize,p)=f1;
            filters2(p,1:filtSize)=f2;

            convv1=imfilter(image_double,  filters1(1:filtSize,p),'conv');
            convv2=imfilter(double(convv1),  filters2(p,1:filtSize),'conv');

            figure
            imagesc(imag(convv2));
            colormap(gray);

        end
    end
```

Comment: what results are you expecting? I used imshow(convv2); it showed me edges with various orientations, what do you mean by "bad convolution result"? You can also use imagesc(imag(convv2)); or imagesc(real(convv2));

Comment: By using only imagesc(convv2), it got error because we cannot use imagesc for complex...Does my code is correct? I think no because some of the convolved images remain the same.

Comment: I(x,y)*real[fx X gy]=real[I(x,y)*(fx X gy)]=real[I(x,y)*fx*gy]. Does that is correct ?

Comment: not imagesc(convv2), but imagesc(imag(convv2)); you choose the image (or real) part of convv2 to display. When you do the convolution, use the full fx,gy instead of real part

Comment: Ah so my code is completely true? can you show my results above, does that is true? the first image by using gabor of size 7x7, the second for a gabor of size 33x33 ...

Comment: your code is correct. I ran it with another image, the result looks good to me :)

Comment: Thank you so much:) I will post my final new question about the svd on gabor filter that I told to you yesterday:) can you help me? :D

Comment: I asked my question about svd on DSP :)