# Create a Gabor filter

Tags: wavelet

Hi friends please refer to the link below and help me in clearing my doubt about gabor filters

[Create a Gabor filter by applying Gabor equation using matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20147891/create-a-gabor-filter-by-applying-gabor-equation-using-matlab?rq=1)

Here by using the above code I am getting the gabor filter gb size 57 * 19 depending on the values of xmax and ymax. I am getting xmax=9 and ymax=28. Is it correct???? What will be the size of gabor filter using above code?? Also please explain why do we use the variable nstds and psi?? Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just got easier. As of R2015b release of the Image Processing Toolbox, you can create a Gabor filter bank using the [gabor](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/gabor.html) function in the image processing toolbox, and you can apply it to an image using [imgaborfilt](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imgaborfilt.html).