# Is the Gabor filter implementation and frequency response in matlab correct?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am trying to implement the Gabor filter in matlab as exactly on the formular (Real part) at
[Wikipedia](https://upload.wikimedia.org/math/7/f/7/7f773702458b003fdc813e4dc76f74e1.png) and [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20147891/create-a-gabor-filter-by-applying-gabor-equation-using-matlab), also shown here [image: Formular] and also plot the frequency response. I have the code below.
Is this implementation and the responses generated correct? 
If not, any help would be appreciated.
[image: Generated responses]

```
function gbImg = gaborFilter()
     a = 512; b = 512;
        delta = 7/3;
        yeta = 1;
        lambda = 7;
        theta.zero = 0;  theta.fortyfive = pi/4; theta.ninety = pi/2;
        theta.onethirtyfive = (3*pi)/4;
        xprime = @(x,y,tetat) ((x * cos(tetat)) + (y* sin(tetat)));
        yprime = @(x,y,tetat) (-(x * sin(tetat)) + (y* cos(tetat)));
        count = 1;
        for th = fieldnames(theta)'
        for i=1:19
            for j=1:19
                h_gb.(th{1})(i,j) = exp(-(xprime(i,j,theta.(th{1}))^2 + (yeta^2 * yprime(i,j,theta.(th{1}))^2))/(2*delta^2) ) * cos(((2*pi*xprime(i,j,theta.(th{1})))/lambda)+pi/2); % + theta.(th{1}));

            end
        end
        [gbImg.(th{1}),fx,fy] = freqz2(h_gb.(th{1}),a,b);
        [Fx,Fy] = meshgrid(fx,fy);
        figure(count);
        mesh(Fx,Fy,abs(gbImg.(th{1})));
        count = count +1;
        end
end
```

Comment: Yup they look fine to me.  Here's one example of a Gabor filter in 3D: http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/TRAPP1/gabimg.gif - does this compare with what your plots produce?

Comment: @rayryeng thanks for the link although above you will find what my plot produces. I just need an inner eye to  confirm/correct this or know if am on the right track.  Am also particular about the code considering different orientation values. You can run the code in matlab, no dependencies.

Comment: It looks correct to me.